# Need help getting Azure AD B2C SSO with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, powerapps, powerapps-portal

I'm trying to set up a page with an Azure AD B2C Sign-Up and Sign-In User Flow, which will then automatically log in to Azure AD as part of the flow. Specifically, I'm trying to create a User Flow that will allow the user to sign in to Azure AD B2C, and automatically have them sign in to Power Apps as a consequence. I'm using the following document as a guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

I've confirmed the pre-requisite part is working. On my Sign up and Sign In page, I'm able to create an account, and I'm able to log in with the account. However, when I log in, I am not being automatically logged in to the Azure AD account as I would expect.

I have a whole bunch of screenshots I've taken with obfuscated data, if they would help, but I think the piece of the puzzle that likely explains the problem is this one:

[image]

This seems pretty similar to how it is configured over on the other side of the equation:

[image]

However, there seems to be a key difference between the two. In the former case, I get a URL of the following format:

https://[B2CDOMAIN].b2clogin.com/[B2CDOMAIN].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=[B2CUserFlow]&[MORE QUERY STRING STUFF]

In the latter, my URL looks like this:

https://[B2CDOMAIN].b2clogin.com/[A GUID]/[B2CUserFlow]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?[MUCH MORE QUERY STRING STUFF BUT NO p= ONE].

I don't know if this gives any indications, or if it's just a red herring. At the moment, I'm not getting any errors or anything - I'm simply not being signed in on the Azure AD side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for this is that you have to select the AAD button to kick off the federation.

If you want to login automatically (no button click) you have to use custom policies.

So you login to your local account and then the policy takes you to AAD where you should be logged in as long as the custom policy is set up for [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

I've never done this for OIDC but I have for SAML and it works there.

Comment: Hey rbrayb - just to be clear, the AAD button is working properly. That's the prerequisite I was describing. What I'm looking to accomplish is to have the AAD login also log the user in to a separate AD account using the steps mentioned in the linked article. From what I can tell, the article you linked describes similar behaviour. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Do you know if there is any audit log I can use to help diagnose where the chain is breaking?

Comment: Confused - are you talking about AAD, B2C or AD? Maybe describe your use case in steps.

Comment: I'm using Azure AD B2C to sign in, using the Sign Up and Sign In User Flow documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-user-flow. I'm then trying to use the documentation here to have that user flow also sign me in to Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: Oh! Now I think I see what you mean! So, if I understand it correctly, that second link is not providing me with a mechanism to have the sign in from Azure AD B2C also sign me in to Azure AD - rather, what it is doing is providing me with a *button* to sign in to Azure AD alongside the existing Azure AD B2C button? If that's the case, I suppose I need to do some more research!